# Element type is invalid: expected a string, Check the render method of App

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap

Every time I try to use something from react-bootstrap, I get this error. " Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports." My export is there for App.js and is imported in index.js so I don't see what's the issue. If I remove the import Nav statement in app.js and take the nav.link tags out, it runs fine.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
<div className="App">
 <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </nav>
 </div>
 <div className="container"> //if I remove this container and the third import statement, it renders with no issues.
    <Nav defaultActiveKey="/home" className="flex-column">
       <Nav.Link href="/home">Active</Nav.Link>
       <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">Link</Nav.Link>
       <Nav.Link eventKey="link-2">Link</Nav.Link>
    </Nav>;
 </div>
</div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: try to remove curly braces from Nav

Comment: It has a parsing error and expects a curly brace.